# Connect two models through id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have trailer model, and a movie model. When a movie is created, I look up all the available trailers and place each one of them in a record with the youtube link and the movie_id of the movie that's been added.

```
def index
  trailer = Trailer.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => trailer.to_json(:only => [:id, :movie_id, :link])
    end
  end
end
```

And the json output,

```
[  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "movie_id":"312221",
    "link":"LsjX5dqHLuw"
  },
  {  
    "id":2,
    "movie_id":"209112",
    "link":"nIGtF3J5kn8"
  },
  {  
    "id":3,
    "movie_id":"209112",
    "link":"yViIi3gie2c"
  },
  {  
    "id":4,
    "movie_id":"209112",
    "link":"Onh7NbZ7F8o"
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "movie_id":"290250",
    "link":"1Vb32Kokbtg"
  },
  {  
    "id":6,
    "movie_id":"290250",
    "link":"1Vb32Kokbtg"
  },
  {  
    "id":7,
    "movie_id":"27205",
    "link":"8hP9D6kZseM"
  },
  {  
    "id":8,
    "movie_id":"157336",
    "link":"ePbKGoIGAXY"
  },
  {  
    "id":9,
    "movie_id":"157336",
    "link":"KlyknsTJk0w"
  },
  {  
    "id":10,
    "movie_id":"157336",
    "link":"nyc6RJEEe0U"
  },
  {  
    "id":11,
    "movie_id":"157336",
    "link":"Lm8p5rlrSkY"
  },
  {  
    "id":12,
    "movie_id":"157336",
    "link":"zSWdZVtXT7E"
  }
]
```

Then I have my movie controller,

```
def index
  @movie = Movie.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => @movie.to_json(include: :trailers)
    end
  end
end
```

The the json output,

```
[  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "title":"Creed",
    "release_date":"2016-01-21",
    "image":"/xSE4NBFDzqedwa4AIj99r1Z7ljF.jpg",
    "user_id":null,
    "created_at":"2016-01-07T20:19:43.849Z",
    "updated_at":"2016-01-07T20:19:43.849Z",
    "movie_id":"312221",
    "backdrop":"/nF4kmc4gDRQU4OJiJgk6sZtbJbl.jpg",
    "crew":null,
    "cast":null,
    "trailers":[  

    ]
  },
  {  
    "id":2,
    "title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice",
    "release_date":"2016-03-24",
    "image":"/eJrlh2g9UGAd7R6mQAOQIIs329H.jpg",
    "user_id":null,
    "created_at":"2016-01-07T20:21:02.615Z",
    "updated_at":"2016-01-07T20:21:02.615Z",
    "movie_id":"209112",
    "backdrop":"/15PbZtjRJ4zgQA8XS0otL70piQi.jpg",
    "crew":null,
    "cast":null,
    "trailers":[  

    ]
  },
  {  
    "id":3,
    "title":"The Nice Guys",
    "release_date":"2016-05-26",
    "image":"/ecD35nDfjsxvDW5BtmK6YAaIkzF.jpg",
    "user_id":null,
    "created_at":"2016-01-07T20:22:05.960Z",
    "updated_at":"2016-01-07T20:22:05.960Z",
    "movie_id":"290250",
    "backdrop":"/aEMBBMuK3BhKIuFu7iFSTXC41Bi.jpg",
    "crew":null,
    "cast":null,
    "trailers":[  

    ]
  },
  {  
    "id":4,
    "title":"Inception",
    "release_date":"2010-07-22",
    "image":"/qmDpIHrmpJINaRKAfWQfftjCdyi.jpg",
    "user_id":null,
    "created_at":"2016-01-08T09:22:30.383Z",
    "updated_at":"2016-01-08T09:22:30.383Z",
    "movie_id":"27205",
    "backdrop":"/s2bT29y0ngXxxu2IA8AOzzXTRhd.jpg",
    "crew":null,
    "cast":null,
    "trailers":[  

    ]
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "title":"Interstellar",
    "release_date":"2014-11-06",
    "image":"/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg",
    "user_id":null,
    "created_at":"2016-01-08T09:22:39.120Z",
    "updated_at":"2016-01-08T09:22:39.120Z",
    "movie_id":"157336",
    "backdrop":"/xu9zaAevzQ5nnrsXN6JcahLnG4i.jpg",
    "crew":null,
    "cast":null,
    "trailers":[  

    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way that I can look up all the trailers that have the same movie_id value as a movie and include them into the json render?

The disered result would be something like this,

```
  {  
    "id":5,
    "title":"Interstellar",
    "release_date":"2014-11-06",
    "image":"/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg",
    "user_id":null,
    "created_at":"2016-01-08T09:22:39.120Z",
    "updated_at":"2016-01-08T09:22:39.120Z",
    "movie_id":"157336",
    "backdrop":"/xu9zaAevzQ5nnrsXN6JcahLnG4i.jpg",
    "crew":null,
    "cast":null,
    "trailers":[  
      {  
        "id":8,
        "movie_id":"157336",
        "link":"ePbKGoIGAXY"
      },
      {  
        "id":9,
        "movie_id":"157336",
        "link":"KlyknsTJk0w"
      },
      {  
        "id":10,
        "movie_id":"157336",
        "link":"nyc6RJEEe0U"
      },
      {  
        "id":11,
        "movie_id":"157336",
        "link":"Lm8p5rlrSkY"
      },
      {  
        "id":12,
        "movie_id":"157336",
        "link":"zSWdZVtXT7E"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query for trailers by `movie_id`:

```
@movie = Movie.first
@trailers = Trailer.where(movie_id: @movie.id)
```

You might want to research Associations. If your Movie has_many Trailers then you can eventually just do:

```
@trailers = @movie.trailers
```

[Ruby on Rails Guide: ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I assume I would add this to my movie controller index definition right? But I don't see how this would add the trailers to my json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show the trailers in movies

you wan to include trailers with movies in that json

```
def index
 @movies = Movie.order('created_at desc')
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json do
       render :json => @movies.to_json(:include => { :trailers => { :only => [:id, :movie_id, :link] } })
     end
   end
 end
```

if you want to include particular trailers for movies

then in movie model

For  rails > 4

```
has_many :trailers, -> { where(id: self.movie_id) }
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I wanted though. I want to include the trailers in my movie model.

Comment: include trailer in movie model means can you please explain not get all here you said "there a way that I can look up all the trailers that have the same movie_id value "

Comment: you want join I think ? then you can do a has many through  association with them and then use join/middle model

Comment: Yes that's what I said, but I also added ` and include them into the json render?` ;). I've eddited my question to show the desired result of including the trailers of a movie into the movie object.

Comment: you need to include it in your render json for movies index method please look into my update post

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I already had the included that trailers in my render. How would rails know what trailers to include though?

Comment: yes in movie model the association will look `has_many :trailers, :conditions => proc  { "movie_id=#{self.id}" }`

Comment: or give the required conditions or id you want to fetch on taht associations

Comment: Thank you for trying to debugging this issue. I've tried adding the has_many relation in my movie model but it's returning an error,

`syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' has_many :trailers, :conditions => proc { movie_id: self.id } ^`

Comment: proc { "movie_id = #{self.id}" }

Comment: Hm, again it returns an error `Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type`

Comment: rails version 4 you `has_many :trailers, -> {where("movie_id = #{self.id}" })`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I was using Rails 4. There seems to be a problem through, `undefined method `id' for #<Trailer`